# How to make arrow straight forward in dia?

Tags: dia

My picture:

[image]

Is there any way to tune that arrow connect straight?

If I change the size of "Known Objects", that will make the upper arrow not straight.

How to fix it?

Comment: Get out your eraser, erase the line, then use a straight-edge to redraw it.

Comment: What application are you using?

Comment: dia. I have already said in my title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think DanH is right, You need to erase the line and use a string edge to draw it again.
The problem you are facing i usually solve it like this.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a snarky wise-crack coupled with an image of the desired result, with no instructions on how to achieve it.  How is this a serious answer?   (Is “string edge” a technical term here?  Is it the name of a function in dia?  I’ve never heard of dia before, so I don’t know anything about it, but a Google search turned up ***this question*** and nothing else that looked relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

1. Go to *View*.
2. Select *Snap to Grid* and *Show Grid*.

This way you can easily make straight lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in UML mode and using Lifeline and you perform what is suggested by user678279 you also need to right click on Lifeline and "Set default connection points distance".

Answer (score 0):

At the left side menu all symbols will be there. 
In the drop down menu, select "other sheets" → "flow chart". 
You will get a straight line.